# Selenium error: The coordinates provided to an interactions operation are invalid

Tags: selenium

Below is the code I am using. It has worked earlier but now it's throwing error. I need to perform right swipe.

```
const TouchAction = wd.TouchAction;
exports.swipeSportsHorizontally = async function (driver) {
    try {   console.log("Calling swipe sports horizontally");
let locationOfSportsIcons = await driver.elementById('com.techmash.playo:id/sports_list_linear_layout').getLocation();
        let action = new TouchAction(driver);
        action
            .press({ x: 800, y: locationOfSportsIcons.y })
            .wait(2000)
            .moveTo({ x: 443, y: locationOfSportsIcons.y })
            .wait(2000)
            .release();
     return await action.perform();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }``
};
```

The error thrown is as follows -

```
{"message":"[performTouchAction([{\"action\":\"press\",\"options\":{\"x\":800,\"y\":243}},{\"action\":\"wait\",\"options\":{\"ms\":2000}},{\"action\":\"moveTo\",\"options\":{\"x\":443,\"y\":243}},{\"action\":\"wait\",\"options\":{\"ms\":2000}},{\"action\":\"release\",\"options\":{}}])] Error response status: 29, , InvalidElementCoordinates - The coordinates provided to an interactions operation are invalid. Selenium error: The coordinates provided to an interactions operation are invalid.","stat...
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Error is loud & clear `Selenium error: The coordinates provided to an interactions operation are invalid` try to get `x: 800` and `x: 443` through your scripts.

Comment: I believe you have your x coordinates backwards.  You say the goal is to swipe right, but you're starting at 800 pixels and swiping to a lower number, 443, which would be left, not right.